# null.collect() returns empty list

Tags: groovy

I was writing unit tests when I happened to find that in groovy the below is `true`

```
null.collect({ //Anything }) == []
```

I could not find the reason for this. What part of groovy is giving this behavior? I checked `NullObject` but that does not have this collect method. So how is this happening?

Comment: [`Object.collect`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect` method is added to all objects at runtime via `DefaultGroovyMethods` class, see [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/), so every class has this methods:

```
class Lol {}

assert new Lol().collect({}) == [null]
assert new Lol().iterator().toList() //is not empty, contains 'this'
```

Answer (score 2):

In groovy `null` has the `iterator()` method which returns an empty iterator. Calling `collect` on null is the same as `null.iterator().collect({/*whatever*/})` and so this will be `[]`.

See the comment on this [bug report](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-7177).

Comment: Why would calling collect call iterator() method on null?

Comment: `null` is an instance of `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject`, not the same `null` as in java. It also has the methods from `DefaultGroovyMethods` added at runtime (see my answer). Groovy does not check if the instance is null but juts invokes the method, it's made to avoid NPE.

Comment: I checked DefaultGroovyMethods -> collect. That is calling iterator in it. So that's why iterator is invoked.

Comment: Yes, `collect` uses `iterator` internally.